# Hide a div if content is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

Philosophy bubble is like a quote/speech bubble div styled which has a sharepoint control inside, the richHtmlField which lets users to type in content while editing page, but if the user chooses to leave it empty, there will be no content in the div so only the bubble will show up in the page which will look funny so i wanna hide the whole div when there is no user entry or basically the div is  empty?? How do you do this in jquery?

```
<div class="philosophy-bubble">
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="carephilosophy" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) selector:

```
$('.philosophy-bubble:empty').hide();
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/F7M4U/).

**Alternative**

You could also use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to find all empty div's and hide:

```
//All divs
$('div').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''
}).hide()

//div's with a certain class
$('.philosophy-bubble').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''
}).hide()

//div with a specific ID
$('#YourDivID').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''
}).hide()
```

..etc.

**Note:** the `:empty` selector will be more performant. [See jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-filter).

Comment: My DIV is empty only if another DIV with certain class is missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845161/how-to-hide-a-div-if-content-are-missing. How can I apply the same for my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDiv =  $('#myDiv');

if (myDiv.text() == '')
{
    myDiv.hide();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
if ($('.philosophy-bubble').is(":empty")){
    $('.philosophy-bubble').hide();
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/XYr9T/1/

**EDIT**

better by using:

```
$('.philosophy-bubble:empty').hide()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/XYr9T/3/