# How to hide a DIV if content are missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ektron

I have some DIV which has contents that are auto generated by Ektron CMS.

Screenshot of the source:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Each parent DIV (`{letter}Serv`) is empty if the DIV class `justPad` doesn't appear at least once. So based on the screenshots, A and C has content but B and D doesn't.

How can I hide the `{letter}Serv` DIV if there is no content inside it?

I have the following class that I can apply:

```
.hideDiv {
     display: none;
}
```

Sample code:

```
<div id="nServ" class="serviceHolder hidOverflow percPadBottom letterCode">
    <h2 class="defaultBlue percPadBottom">N</h2>
        <span id="ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_Collection15">
        <a href="#ViewEditorsMenu" data-ektron-editorsmenu-id="EktronEditorsMenu3c275505-4a2c-4384-bf36-081bc3e69279" onclick="return false;" class="EktronEditorsMenuMarker"><img src="/WorkArea/images/application/pin_grey.gif" alt="Editor's Menu" title="Editor's Menu" /></a>
        <ul id="EktronEditorsMenu3c275505-4a2c-4384-bf36-081bc3e69279" class="EktronEditorsMenu" style="display:none;">
            {CONTENTS}
        </ul>
        <div class="justPad"><a class="defaultLinks" href="link">Nephrology</a></div>
        <div class="justPad"><a class="defaultLinks" href="link">Neurology</a></div>
        <div class="justPad"><a class="defaultLinks" href="link">Nutrition</a></div>
    </span>
</div>

<div id="bServ" class="serviceHolder hidOverflow percPadBottom letterCode">
    <h2 class="defaultBlue percPadBottom">B</h2>
        <span id="ctl00_BodyPlaceHolder_Collection15">
        <a href="#ViewEditorsMenu" data-ektron-editorsmenu-id="EktronEditorsMenu3c275505-4a2c-4384-bf36-081bc3e69279" onclick="return false;" class="EktronEditorsMenuMarker"><img src="/WorkArea/images/application/pin_grey.gif" alt="Editor's Menu" title="Editor's Menu" /></a>
        <ul id="EktronEditorsMenu3c275505-4a2c-4384-bf36-081bc3e69279" class="EktronEditorsMenu" style="display:none;">
            {CONTENTS}
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `div:empty {display:none}` you can check if div is empty

Comment: That would work except the DIV will have other content inside it. I only want to hide it if `justPad` DIV isn't present at least once.

Comment: I guess this doesnt work because his div isnt actually empty

Comment: Just get childElements of the parent div.  Loop through the child elements if any are justPad then don't hide if none are justPad then hide using display:none.

Comment: Please add the code itself, and not just a screenshot. This isn't just easier for us to search for keywords, but will also be more useful for future users with similar issues.

Comment: @DarkAshelin Good point. I will do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should find all of your empty Divs and hide them.

```
$('div.serviceHolder:not(:has(div.justPad))').hide()
```

Comment: Thank you, does that mean you'll accept it as the correct answer?

Comment: Yes but I can't yet :/ Thank you also!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each div and looks for children length, if null .hide() the div:

```
$('.hidOverflow').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $items = $this.children('.justPad'),
        itemAmount = $items.length;

    if(itemAmount <= 0) {
        $this.hide();
        // or if you want to use your CSS-class
        $this.addClass('hideDiv');
    }
});
```

edit: Added version where we are using your CSS-class instead of the .hide()-function.

Comment: Probably want to iterate over all .serviceHolder

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Best case would be to have a specific class just for this loop, like "js-hide-if-empty" or along those lines.

Comment: @ninja Thanks for the code and it works but I went with @ Shrikke's solution as it's simpler and works with just one line. This also worked for anyone who might be interested. I up voted your answer

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div[id$=Serv]").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':empty')){
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else{
            $(this).show();
        }
});
});
```

Hope it helps ....

Comment: Thanks for the code and it works but I went with @ Shrikke's solution as it's simpler and works with just one line. This also worked for anyone who might be interested. I up voted your answer